# What does this split expression mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  print join("\t", (split /:/)[0, 2, 1, 5] ), "\n";
}
```

What does `(split /:/)[0, 2, 1, 5]` mean here?

Comment: @mirod ,it cuts off the trailing `LF`:)

Comment: You might try a Perl tutorial, such as <i>Learning Perl</i>. Many of your questions are answered with a little directed learning. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means

```
my @fields            = split /:/, $_;
my @fields_to_display = ($fields[0], $fields[2], $fields[1], $fields[5]);
```

create a list by splitting the line on :, then take elements 0,2,1,5 of this list

Answer (score 7):

It's a [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).

Of the values returned by the [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), it returns the first (index 0), the third (index 2), the second (index 1) and the sixth (index 5), in that order.

Honestly, this should have been obvious if you had run the program. Go ahead and try it!

Answer (score 4):

It splits the string stored in `$_` ([see perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)) on given regular expression (in this case a single `:`) and picks elements number 0, 2, 1 and 5 from the resulting array.

Comment: I think $_ is the single hardest concept for people to get about PERL.

Comment: @Tremmors, It's the second. The first is the concept that the language is called "Perl".

Comment: @Tremmors, As for the use of `$_`, I don't know how "If EXPR is omitted, splits the `$_` string." can be any clearer. Or are you really saying the concept that people have problems with is reading the docs to figure out how a function works?

Comment: @ikegami: most languages don’t have a default “it” variable, so I guess that can be a surprise for Perl newcomers.

Comment: @zoul, Neither does Perl. What it has is default arguments. Lots of languages have default arguments. Just like in those languages, one must read the docs to find out what the defaults are. That some of those defaults are variables such as `$_`, `@_`, `@ARGV` and `\*ARGV` is a little unusual, but no more confusing than a default of `2`.

Comment: Coming from a strongly typed language background, anyone who sees it for the first time is going to say "You mean there's some variable in the background that just gets populated and passed in whenever I forget to specify a variable?" That's usually when their eyes glaze over and they walk away muttering about how strange Perl programmers are.

Comment: @Tremmors, That may be, but it's tangential. People finding it weird (or even problematic) that Perl uses global vars doesn't make it hard to understand how `split` works when arguments are omitted.

Comment: @Tremmors: Perl *is* strongly typed.  You just don’t understand what its types are.

Comment: @tchrist - He's conflating a number of issues: strong typing and default arguments, weird languages and the people that use them. If he uses Maven, he's surely seen convention over configuration and knows the value of defaults.